# how to delete a single value from mysql table

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

i have the following data in the table

```
name        price
red wine    150
white wine  300
```

i want to delete the value 300

i used the below query

```
update cms.wine set price =null where name='white wine'
```

it gives me the below error

> You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without
>   a WHERE that  uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the
>   option in Preferences ->  SQL Queries and reconnect.

Comment: can this query be executed without toggling safe mode

Comment: @John Woo He wants to update a value in a specific row, not delete the entire row.

Comment: you have to delete on the base of id in that case

Comment: you should add a primary key column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that:

```
DELETE FROM cms.wine WHERE price = '300' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ya 1 more question  how to i avoid retriving null valuesin a select query for example i want to retrive a column and some fields in the column are null . is there anyway i can prevent those null values from bieng retrived

Comment: Read OP post. He said that want delete record with '300'

Comment: Op says he wants to delete the value not row

Answer (score 4):

Do like this:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

and then:

```
update cms.wine set price =null where name='white wine;'
```

But you should do on the basis of id column as it will delete all records who has name equal to **white wine**

like this:

```
update cms.wine set price =null where id=1;
```

In this it will delete only that particular record which has primary key value 1.

you should add a primary key column in the table so that your table will look like this and make the column primary key so that its always unique for every record:

```
id      name          price
1       red wine      150
2       white wine    300
```